# ERROR 1307 (0x0000051B) - While copying with Robocopy - None of the known sollutions work

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems, robocopy

I'm trying to copy a folder from one harddrive to another using the folowing robocopy options:

```
robocopy "H:\Source" "T:\target" /E /COPY:DATSO /R:1 /W:1 /DCOPY:T /Z /LOG:T:\Belfirst_copy.log /NP
```

For files where the owner is not the Administrator, but some specific domain user, i get the following error:

```
ERROR 1307 (0x0000051B) Copying NTFS Security to Destination Directory T:\target\...(a lot of files/dirs)
This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.
```

I have tried all the proposed solutions i could find:

- Give the Domain user i'm logged in with, and running the script as,
  full access to the source, and target directory.
- Give the Domain user
  i'm logged in with, and running the script as, the "Restore files and
  directories" priviledge.
- Run as administrator
- Run as a bat file
- Log off and log on again and retry
- use the /B option
- Try without the /COPY:S option

For obvious reasons copying without the /COPY:O option solves the problem. But that beats the purpose of course.

What am i missing?

Platform: Windows Server 2008 R2

(This is highly related to "[Robocopy failure with Windows Server 2008 Scheduled Task](https://serverfault.com/questions/236963/robocopy-failure-with-windows-server-2008-scheduled-task)", but i don't have enough reputation yet to add a comment there.)

Comment: I tried it again today, and it worked. Not sure if i made a mistake last time, of if there's something else that's different. I'll leave this post in case anyone else comes accros this.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you can only acquire NTFS ownership of filesystem objects for yourself. You cannot set the ownership to a third person. (This prevents users from e.g. storing compromising or incriminating data under the ownership of another, unsuspecting person.)

There is a "restore files and directories" privilege in the security policy. Microsoft [states](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/restore-files-and-directories):

> This security setting [...] determines which users can set valid security principals as the owner of an object.

Apparently, you need this privilege to copy ownership. Robocopy must run in a security context that allows setting ownership to arbitrary principals.

By default, local administrators have this privilege:

> By default, this right is granted to the Administrators, Backup Operators, and Server Operators groups on domain controllers, and to the Administrators and Backup Operators groups on stand-alone servers.

(The "restore files and directories" privilege is part of the policy. You may need to log off and on again for it to become effective.)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this trouble.  I wrote a batch file to robocopy the current logged in user and copy all his profile folder to a network shared location.  Using variables and this combination of switches every folder copied without an errors. A command has to be created for each individual folder, but it works.  You may have to give the user permission to create a folder in the network share, or create it prior to first time backup.

robocopy "%HOMEPATH%\FOLDER" "\SERVER\NETWORK_SHARE\%USERNAME%\FOLDER" /s /mir /zb /b /copy:dat